# SUM function in a calculated column

Tags: list

I am running SharePoint 2013 Standard Edition. I have a custom list that includes three columns:

- Question type (a choice column with three choices: "Parliamentary
  question", "Petition" and "Open question")
- Status (a choice column with two choices: "In progress"and "New")
- "No. of Parliamentary questions in progress" (a calculated column which I would like to display the number of questions in progress).

If the question type is "Parliamentary question" AND the status is "In progress," I want the "No. of Parliamentary questions in progress" column to display the number of questions in progress at any given time.

I started with the following formula but am unsure how to end it. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

`=SUM(IF([Question Type]]="Parliamentary question", [Status]="In progress”)` ...?

Comment: SharePoint is **not** Excel. Formulas only operate on its own Item, it can't access other Items

Answer (score 4):

When you try to use this `Summation equation` to a `Calculated Column` , I think it does not give you meaning for each row , where each row will have the same number as the following

```
Quest   Status       No. of Parliamentary questions in progress
Q1      InProgress   2
Q2      InProgress   2
```

Also , you will face issue with some fields to use it in calculated column . So I suggest to you to `Group by` your list with `Status` field and Set the `Total` to `Status count` that will show as the following and I think it will match your requirements.

[image]

**Steps :**

- Go to list setting > at the bottom of page > click on Create a new view
- Set view name > select the files that you need (Quest - Status)
- In view `GroupBy` Section > Select your `Status` field.
- In `Total` > Select `Count` for `Status` as shown below.

[image]

Comment: What are these EvOWORX thingy in your images?

Comment: Dear @BennySkogberg , This is only as a watermark for my screenshot image (it's not a trademark it refers to private blog name https://blog.devoworx.net/ ) , if this opposite of community rule and policy or moderators don't want to use it , I will remove it, and I don't try to do it again I only appreciate the community rule and policy , please let me know and I am so sorry for any unintentional behavior from me

Comment: No worries, I'm just curious - I use my own name from dev tenant in screenshots. No harm done ;)

Comment: Thanks my brother and teacher  and I am so proud to talk with you :)

Comment: LOL, I'm just another guy who just happen to be mod here. Thanks for sharing your knowledge!!!

Comment: very nice workaround.